# Revert a CSS class back to original when new selection in dropdown menu is chosen

Tags: javascript, html, css, onchange

I have a dropdown menu that triggers a different set of menus depending on the first selection. Then based on the next selection I want to show a div with information in it. If the second selection changes I want to hide the content displayed and display the new content for the new selection. The problem I am having is when the new selection is made the old content does not hide and the new content just adds on to it.

I do not understand jquery so I am using javascript and I have tried changing the class name based on the div ID using .classlist.remove and .add. I have also tried creating loops to check if the class name exists and change it to a different class name.

```js
function populate(s1, s2) {
    var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
    var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
    s2.innerHTML = "";
    if (s1.value == "Auto") {
      var optionArray = ["|Please Select The Insurance Company", "nationwideauto|Nationwide", "progressiveauto|Progressive", "safeco|Safeco"];
    } else if (s1.value == "Home") {
      var optionArray = ["|Please Select The Insurance Company", "cabrillo|Cabrillo", "gulfstream|Gulfstream", "capitalpreferred|Capital Preferred"];
    } else if (s1.value == "Commercial") {
      var optionArray = ["|Please Select The Insurance Company", "bankers|Bankers", "travelers|Travelers", "progressive|Progressive"];
    }
    for (var option in optionArray) {
      var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
      var newOption = document.createElement("option");
      newOption.value = pair[0];
      newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
      s2.options.add(newOption);
    }
  }

  function toggle() {
    var element = document.getElementById('slct2').value;
    document.getElementById(element).classList.remove('inv');
    document.getElementById(element).classList.add('vis');
  }
```

```css
  .inv {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .vis {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id, 'slct2')">
  <option value "">Please Select The Type of Claim</option>
  <option value="Auto">Auto Insurance Claim</option>
  <option value="Home">Property Insurance Claim</option>
  <option value="Commercial">Commercial Insurance Claim</option>
</select>

<select id="slct2" name="slct2" onchange="toggle(this.id)"></select>

<div id="nationwideauto" class="inv">Content 1</div>

<div id="progressiveauto" class="inv">Content 2</div>

<div id="safeco" class="inv">Content 3</div>
```

I have only created the first few divs to test code and the expected result would be when you select "Auto" in the first dropdown then the auto insurance companies show in the second dropdown (which works). Then when you select a company from the second dropdown it displays the content in a div (which works). The problem I am having is when a new selection is made in dropdown 2 I cannot figure out how to hide the div with the original content and show the div with the new content. My function toggle() is the problem and I have read and searched for three days straight now without being able to find a solution that works.

Comment: Use [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods), rather than add and remove.

Comment: I have tried that and it only toggles it on and off if the same selection is made a second time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `vis` class from all elements, and then apply it to the selected element. There is no need to remove the `inv` class, as the `vis` class will override it. Instead of using toggle, we can explicitly use add and remove because we know only 0 or 1 item will have the class at any given time:

```js
function populate(s1, s2) {
  var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
  var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
  s2.innerHTML = "";
  if (s1.value == "Auto") {
    var optionArray = ["|Please Select The Insurance Company", "nationwideauto|Nationwide", "progressiveauto|Progressive", "safeco|Safeco"];
  } else if (s1.value == "Home") {
    var optionArray = ["|Please Select The Insurance Company", "cabrillo|Cabrillo", "gulfstream|Gulfstream", "capitalpreferred|Capital Preferred"];
  } else if (s1.value == "Commercial") {
    var optionArray = ["|Please Select The Insurance Company", "bankers|Bankers", "travelers|Travelers", "progressive|Progressive"];
  }
  for (var option in optionArray) {
    var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = pair[0];
    newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
    s2.options.add(newOption);
  }
}

function toggle() {
  var element = document.getElementById('slct2').value;
  var selected = document.getElementById(element)
  const vis = document.getElementsByClassName('vis')
  vis.length && vis[0].classList.remove('vis')
  selected.classList.add('vis')

}
```

```css
.inv {
  display: none;
}

.vis {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id, 'slct2')">
  <option value "">Please Select The Type of Claim</option>
  <option value="Auto">Auto Insurance Claim</option>
  <option value="Home">Property Insurance Claim</option>
  <option value="Commercial">Commercial Insurance Claim</option>
</select>

<select id="slct2" name="slct2" onchange="toggle(this.id)"></select>

<div id="nationwideauto" class="inv">Content 1</div>

<div id="progressiveauto" class="inv">Content 2</div>

<div id="safeco" class="inv">Content 3</div>
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. I didn't even think of that

Comment: No worries. If you ever need anymore help, feel free to ask.